# Rehomed dog potty training habits keep regressing

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I'm new here.  I searched for rehomed dog questions, but didn't come up with much.  So here goes...

We adopted a ~15 month old male basset hound from a family a few months ago.  The owner claimed that he was potty trained except for "a few accidents here and there."  Unfortunately it seems that this was a partial truth, at best.  He's regressed badly in his training in the few months since.  He's now peeing and pooping in the house and in his crate on a regular basis, occasionally even in our presence.  Sometimes he'll even go outside for a potty break and then come right back inside and make a mess within minutes.

Has anybody had experience with re-potty training a rehomed dog?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you going about retraining him? Do you reward for going outside? It's quite unusual to pee in a crate for a dog, have you taken him to a vet to check for an infection?

Comment: He goes outside on a 25' cable, I'd say he's supervised 50% of the time.  When he does go outside, he typically is praised and given a treat.

Comment: so he could be going without you noticing or without praise?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: You said he is going in his _crate_, too? Dogs really, really don't like to do that. Is there some sort of health issue going on? When's the last time he's been to the vet?

Comment: He's been to the vet a few times in the months we've had him.  I suppose perhaps I overplayed that a bit.  Accidents in the house are MUCH more frequent than anything that happens in the crate.  But he has indeed left messes in the crate.  I suppose that checking for an infection is worth looking into.

Comment: Potty training a rehomed dog is really no different from training any other dog, so check all the other toilet training questions in the site for more advice. But it could well be that the dog got somewhat confused due to the rehoming which could be the cause for him "losing" some of his toilet training

Answer (score 4):

You need to go back to the beginning of house training: Confine him to a crate whenever you cannot be actively watching him, take him out at least every hour when not crated (at first -- he should be able to hold it much longer). Give lots of praise and treats when he goes outside. Watch vigilantly for him starting to go when inside and interrupt him and immediately take him out if he starts to go inside. When he does go outside, don't assume his bladder is empty. Male dogs especially use urine to mark territory, so one little squirt means there is probably more. He should get the idea quickly that urinating outside is rewarding and do more quickly. So wait for more. For now, don't ever just tie him up outside. Wait until you see him go so your can praise and reward him.

Housetraining is a lot of work and a pain in the butt, but it will pay off in the long run. I finished training my 7th puppy a few months ago and she had not had an accident in over two months now. The longer you let accidents go on, the harder it will be to teach him that going inside is not acceptable.